# Export uitable object with coloured cells to png or other image format

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to export and save a table that is being visualized within the user interface to .png or other image format. Also pdf would do the trick. That's the code i wrote to generate the table and coloutt the cells.

````
app.UITable.Data=CreateUITable(app, app.deltas_table, app.deltas_threshold);
        
%% GUI TABLE COLOURING (ANALYSIS MODULE)
        
        
% Hightlight over-threshold values in red
        
[redRows, redCols]= find( abs(app.UITable.Data{:,2}) >= app.deltas_threshold);
z = uistyle('BackgroundColor',[1 0.6 0.6]);
addStyle(app.UITable, z ,'cell',[redRows, redCols]);
addStyle(app.UITable, z ,'cell',[redRows, redCols+1]);
addStyle(app.UITable, z ,'cell',[redRows, redCols+2]);
addStyle(app.UITable, z ,'cell',[redRows, redCols+3]);
        
        
% Hightlight under-threshold values in green
        
[greenRows, greenCols]= find( abs(app.UITable.Data{:,2}) <= app.deltas_threshold);
n = uistyle('BackgroundColor',[0.6 1  0.6]);
addStyle(app.UITable, n ,'cell', [greenRows, greenCols]);
addStyle(app.UITable, n ,'cell',[greenRows, greenCols+1]);
addStyle(app.UITable, n ,'cell',[greenRows, greenCols+2]);
addStyle(app.UITable, n ,'cell',[greenRows, greenCols+3]);
        
% Hightlight NaN values in gray
        
NaNidxs = ismissing(app.UITable.Data);
[NaNrow,NaNcol] = find(NaNidxs);
s = uistyle('BackgroundColor',1/255*[200,200,200]);
addStyle(app.UITable,s,'cell',[NaNrow, NaNcol]);
addStyle(app.UITable,s,'cell',[NaNrow, NaNcol+1]);
addStyle(app.UITable,s,'cell',[NaNrow, NaNcol+2]);
addStyle(app.UITable,s,'cell',[NaNrow, NaNcol+3]); ```
````

I tried this way:

```
f = figure;
uit = uitable(f, 'Data', table2cell(app.Uitable.Data));
saveas(f, 'figure.png');
```

but the colours don't appear on the image and so the variable names, of course.

and tried also with `exportgraphics`:

```
exportgraphics(app.UItable,filename)
```

and I also tried to export the uipanel that contains the uitable object, but nothing happened.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thank you!